# agrupar por semestre/ano PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá, tenho uma tabela com campo data, quero agrupar por semestre/ano, fiz assim.

```
SELECT
    SUM(quantidade) quantidade,
    YEAR(DATA) ano
FROM
    tbmanipulacao
GROUP BY
    YEAR(DATA),
    MONTH(DATA) <=6,
    MONTH(DATA) >6
ORDER BY
    ano
ASC
```

o retorno tá assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a pergunta é, como identificar o semestre ? (saber que aquela quantidade pertence ao 1º ou 2º semestre).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para separar por semestre, precisa gerar essa informação no SELECT.
Pegando a lógica da sua query, pode fazer `IF(MONTH(data) <= 6, 1, 2) semestre`.
Isso vai gerar "1" quando o mês for igual ou menor que 6 e "2" para 7 ou maior, depois basta usar essa informação, que tem o alias "semestre" no `group by`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(quantidade) quantidade,
    YEAR(DATA) ano,
    IF(MONTH(data) <= 6, 1, 2) semestre
FROM
    teste
GROUP BY
    ano, semestre
```

Aqui um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aeb9c/10