# Identificar registros sequencias entre um curto período de tempo

Tags: php, sql

Preciso da ajuda de vocês para identificar registros sequenciais no meu banco de dados em um curto período de tempo

Exemplo:

```
$qdt_acao_suspeitas = 5; //5 ações consecutivas
$tempo = 10; //10 minuntos
```

Se o usuário X realizar a ação mais de `$qdt_acao_suspeitas` entre o tempo `$tempo` exibe um echo informando...

Registros sequencias no meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Descrição:

mat3us fez 5 ações iguais em menos de 10 minutos

guilherme21 fez 5 ações iguais em menos de 10 minutos

Já tentei algo como

```
$flood = $pdo->querySELECT usuario,action,data,count(action) FROM eventos GROUP BY usuario,data having count(action) > 5");
```

em um while eu faço a seguinte requisição

```
if($flood > 0){
...
}
```

gostaria de um retorno de todos os usuários que batem com minha requisição

mas eu tenho certeza que meu `SELECT` não tem muito haver com oque eu quero fazer e já estou sem ideias

Comment: e quanto é o "curto período"? 10min? isso vai ser complicado de fazer na query, se fosse por 1 minuto ou 1 hora, era só agrupar a data por minuto ou hora e fazer um count, vai ter de fazer isso no código

Comment: Qual o Banco ? Supondo Mysql , pesquise por lead / lag de window functions , que permitem ver os registros anteriores de uma sql , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-lead-and-lag-function/  , também timediff para o cálculo da diferença https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timediff.asp , outrsos SGBD tem soluções semelhantes

Comment: @RicardoPontual supondo que seja 1 hora, como ficaria na pratica?

Comment: @Motta eu ja tentei também, da o erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in ...

Comment: da uma olhada nessa outra resposta pra ter uma ideia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460199/57220

Comment: @javinha lead e lag funciona , mas creio que dependa do ambiente , versão etc

Comment: @RicardoPontual fiz no mesmo raciocino e sempre retorna o Fatal errol =@

Comment: bom sem ver o código fica dificil ajudar... edita e coloca na pergunta

Comment: Este também seria o caso de se pensar o caso de uma function, regras muitas complicadas podem ser resolvidas por function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta modificar seu select.
Considerando que cada acesso pode ser considerado flood ou não dependendo dos acessos anteriores, você pode adicionar uma coluna pra contar esses acessos assim:

```
SELECT usuario,action,data,
(
SELECT count(*)>=5 FROM eventos
where eventos.usuario = x.usuario and 
data between DATE_ADD(x.data, INTERVAL -10 MINUTE) and x.data
) as is_flood
FROM eventos as x
```

A coluna is_flood terá a informação se o evento vem seguido de 5 eventos anteriores dentro de 10 minutos.

Comment: Aparentemente está funcionando, OBRIGADO de verdade por ajuda, se eu pude recompensa me avisa =D. Só uma dúvida, esta retornando todos os dados, gostaria de agrupar por usuário, como ficaria? uso um group by?

Comment: Adicionei um GROUP BY data e deu certo. Muito obrigado =D